# check if bitmap is null

Tags: android, xamarin.android

```
Bitmap bmp;
bmp = (Android.Graphics.Bitmap)data.Extras.Get("data");
CallToFunction (bmp);
```

Calling a function with Bitmap.

```
private void CallToFunction(Bitmap bmp)
    {
       if(bmp)
         {
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
private void CallToFunction(Bitmap bmp)
{
       if (bmp != null)
       {
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Not too much to go on here however I suspect that you are getting a null reference exception when you do an implicit conversion to the bitmap where "data" could be null?

Check that data is not empty before converting to a bitmap.

```
var data = data.Extras.Get("data");
if(data != null){

    CallToFunction ((Android.Graphics.Bitmap)data);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check via

```
if(data.Extras.Get("data")!=null && data.Extras.Get("data") instanceOf Bitmap){
     CallToFunction ((Android.Graphics.Bitmap)data.Extras.Get("data"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following it will check if bitmap is not 
 not null only then that method will be called other it will not 
 called that method.

```
      Bitmap bmp;
       bmp = (Android.Graphics.Bitmap)data.Extras.Get("data");
       if (bmp != null)
       {
         CallToFunction (bmp);
       }
```